# How to replace the last occurrence of a substring in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to replace the last occurrence of a substring in Ruby. What's the easiest way?
For example, in **abc123abc123**, I want to replace the last **abc** to **ABC**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.0 we can use `\K` which removes any text matched before it from the returned match. Combine with a greedy operator and you get this:

```
'abc123abc123'.sub(/.*\Kabc/, 'ABC')
#=> "abc123ABC123"
```

This is about 1.4 times faster than using capturing groups as Hirurg103 suggested, but that speed comes at the cost of lowering readability by using a lesser-known pattern.

more info on `\K`: https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html

Answer (score 40):

How about

```
new_str = old_str.reverse.sub(pattern.reverse, replacement.reverse).reverse
```

For instance:

```
irb(main):001:0> old_str = "abc123abc123"
=> "abc123abc123"
irb(main):002:0> pattern="abc"
=> "abc"
irb(main):003:0> replacement="ABC"
=> "ABC"
irb(main):004:0> new_str = old_str.reverse.sub(pattern.reverse, replacement.reverse).reverse
=> "abc123ABC123"
```

Comment: Clear and easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 22):

```
"abc123abc123".gsub(/(.*(abc.*)*)(abc)(.*)/, '\1ABC\4')
#=> "abc123ABC123"
```

But probably there is a better way...

Edit:

...which Chris kindly provided in the comment below.

So, as `*` is a greedy operator, the following is enough:

```
"abc123abc123".gsub(/(.*)(abc)(.*)/, '\1ABC\3')
#=> "abc123ABC123"
```

Edit2:

There is also a solution which neatly illustrates parallel array assignment in Ruby:

```
*a, b = "abc123abc123".split('abc', -1)
a.join('abc')+'ABC'+b
#=> "abc123ABC123"
```

Comment: Due to greedy matching, just `str.sub(/(.*)abc/, '\1ABC')` should suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also thought this problem can be solved by regular expression, but don't know how. You did it. Thanks again!

Comment: to build upon @ChrisJohnsen answer:

`class String
  def sub_last(str_match, str_sub)
    self.sub(/(.*)#{Regexp.quote(str_match)}/, '\1' + str_sub)
  end
end`

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this with [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-sub) and greedy regexp `.*` like this:

```
'abc123abc123'.sub(/(.*)abc/, '\1ABC')
```

Comment: Why gsub instead of sub? You'll only be replacing one occurence (that was kind of the point).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity you are right - fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here's another possible solution:

```
>> s = "abc123abc123"
=> "abc123abc123"

>> s[s.rindex('abc')...(s.rindex('abc') + 'abc'.length)] = "ABC"
=> "ABC"

>> s
=> "abc123ABC123"
```

Answer (score 5):

When searching in huge streams of data, using `reverse` will definitively* lead to performance issues. I use `string.rpartition`*:

```
sub_or_pattern = "!"
replacement = "?"
string = "hello!hello!hello"

array_of_pieces = string.rpartition sub_or_pattern
( array_of_pieces[(array_of_pieces.find_index sub_or_pattern)] =  replacement ) rescue nil
p array_of_pieces.join
# "hello!hello?hello"
```

The same code must work with a string with no occurrences of `sub_or_pattern`:

```
string = "hello_hello_hello"
# ...
# "hello_hello_hello"
```

*`rpartition`  uses `rb_str_subseq()` internally. I didn't check if that function returns a copy of the string, but I think it preserves the chunk of memory used by that part of the string. `reverse` uses `rb_enc_cr_str_copy_for_substr()`, which suggests that copies are done all the time -- although maybe in the future a smarter `String` class may be implemented (having a flag `reversed` set to true, and having all of its functions operating backwards when that is set), as of now, it is inefficient.

Moreover, `Regex` patterns can't be simply reversed. The question only asks for replacing the last occurrence of a sub-string, so, that's OK, but readers in the need of something more robust won't benefit from the most voted answer (as of this writing)

Answer (score 2):

simple and efficient:

```
s = "abc123abc123abc"
p = "123"
s.slice!(s.rindex(p), p.size)
s == "abc123abcabc"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Solved my problem! Simple and efficient, as grosser said.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "abc123abc123"
pattern = /abc/
replacement = "ABC"

matches = string.scan(pattern).length
index = 0
string.gsub(pattern) do |match|
  index += 1
  index == matches ? replacement : match
end
#=> abc123ABC123
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used this handy helper method quite a bit:

```
def gsub_last(str, source, target)
  return str unless str.include?(source)
  top, middle, bottom = str.rpartition(source)
  "#{top}#{target}#{bottom}"
end
```

If you want to make it more Rails-y, extend it on the String class itself:

```
class String
  def gsub_last(source, target)
    return self unless self.include?(source)
    top, middle, bottom = self.rpartition(source)
    "#{top}#{target}#{bottom}"
  end
end
```

Then you can just call it directly on any String instance, eg `"fooBAR123BAR".gsub_last("BAR", "FOO") == "fooBAR123FOO"`

Answer (score 0):

```
.gsub /abc(?=[^abc]*$)/, 'ABC'
```

Matches a "abc" and then asserts ((?=) is positive lookahead) that no other characters up to the end of the string are "abc".